# Story of children killing monster after parents don't believe them?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

50+ years old. Children are being killed, parents ignore their claims that there is a monster. Kids take matters into own hands one night and adults find large bones, too large to be those of a human, in a cemetery marked by tiny (child-sized) toothmarks. I know the story is sort of like It but it predates It by many years.